# How to exclude Weekend and compare current dates in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm comparing  data  with current date - 1 and  -2  dates in my table.
Sample  Data  :

```
Name  cnt  Dates
Mills 20    2022-07-15
Mills 15    2022-07-14
Mills 10    2022-07-13
```

I have  written query where  it  compares  current date - 1 and Current date - 2

```
SELECT Name,Date,`T-2`,`T-1`,Diff
    FROM (
SELECT  T.Name  ,T.Date,T.`T-1`,TT.`T-2`,TT.`T-2` - T.`T-1`  AS Diff FROM 
(select  Name, Date, cnt AS 'T-1' from Acct where date = curdate() - 1 )T
INNER JOIN 
(select  Name, Date, cnt AS 'T-2' from Acct where date = curdate() - 2)TT
ON T.Name = TT.Name )T
```

Now  when I execute  this  query Current date  (2022-07-18) it is  taking  -1  as  2022-07-17 and -2 as  2022-07-16.
I want  to exclude  weekends  and  compare  those  with Friday and Thursday .

**Out put  :**

```
Name   T-1   T-2  DIFF 
Mills   20   15    5
```

Comment: What do you want if today is Tuesday?

Comment: if  today is  tuesday then Current  date  - 1  (i.e.monday) and  Current date - 2  I need  to fetch for  Friday like that  I'm looking  @Serg

Comment: Are weekends excluded from the base table ? e.g. Do 2022-07-16(Saturday) and 2022-07-17(Sunday) exist in the table at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `curdate() - 1` with conditional expression `curdate() - case weekday(curdate()) when 0 then 3 when 6 then 2 else 1 end`. Similar for `curdate() - 2`

```
SELECT Name,Date,`T-2`,`T-1`,Diff
    FROM (
SELECT  T.Name  ,T.Date,T.`T-1`,TT.`T-2`,TT.`T-2` - T.`T-1`  AS Diff FROM 
(select  Name, Date, cnt AS 'T-1' 
 from Acct 
 where date = curdate() - case weekday(curdate()) when 0 then 3 when 6 then 2 else 1 end) T
INNER JOIN 
(select  Name, Date, cnt AS 'T-2' 
 from Acct 
 where date = curdate() - case weekday(curdate()) when 0 then 4 when 1 then 4 when 6 then 3 else 2 end) TT
ON T.Name = TT.Name ) T
```

[weekday()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday)

Comment: perfect  I too have  followed  the  same  way

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @zi = curdate();
SET @x =   DAYOFWEEK(@zi);
SELECT @x;

case when  @x = 2 then  date = curdate() - 3 else  date = curdate() - 1 end
```